# Viagra for pain management

Tags: human-biology, pain

Not all men who take Viagra experience any sexual side effects about 40% have no change of sexual abilities on the pill. However like many women the drug in such cases cause a [strong pain reduction](http://www.forbes.com/sites/alicegwalton/2013/12/10/viagra-might-help-ease-menstrual-pain/) without any considerable side effects. Also in some cases is able to eliminate persistent nausea and increase oxygen flow through the lungs.

Could Viagra be used for cancer patients or others who need to manage pain?

### Update:

[Roles for Sildenafil(or Viagra) in Enhancing Drug Sensitivity in Cancer](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3107342/)

Comment: Amazingly there is a paper on this: [Roles for Sildenafil in Enhancing Drug Sensitivity in Cancer](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3107342/)